# Max value of a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am looking to find the max value of this function: log(x^(sqrt(2))) - x^3 + 4
I am having trouble with how to go about this problem. Any help is great. What I have right now is:

y =@(x) log(x).^(sqrt(2)) - x.^3 + 4 ;
x0 = 1;
x = fzero(y,x0);
disp(x);

Comment: ```fzero(y, x0)``` finds the root of the function ```y``` with initial guess ```x0```. You are not looking for roots, you are trying to find the max value. If you want to use ```fzero```, you need to apply it to the derivative of ```y```, which you can compute either by hand, or symbolically, using ```diff``` if you have the symbolic toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of 
$$
\log(x^{\sqrt{2}})-x^{3}+4=\sqrt{2}\log(x)-x^{3}+4
$$
 is
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{x}-3x^{2}.
$$
Setting the derivative to zero and solving for $x$,
$$
x=\frac{\sqrt[6]{2}}{\sqrt[3]{3}}.
$$
You can check that this is, in fact, the point at which the extrema is attained.
Plugging this $x$ into the original function and simplifying, the maximum is
$$
\left(24-2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}\log\left(9/2\right)\right)/6\approx3.17408.
$$
(P.s. ~ This site is generally not for MATLAB, try [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) instead)